# Redis pattern for 'keys' command that returns all except keys containing specific char

Tags: redis

I want to get all keys from Redis that don't contain a specific character, namely ':'

Example:

```
Keys in redis: ab, cd, a:b, c:d
Query: keys ???
Expected result: ab, cd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with the [`KEYS`](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command, as it only supports the following glob-style patterns:

> - `h?llo` matches `hello`, `hallo` and `hxllo`
> - `h*llo` matches `hllo` and `heeeello`
> - `h[ae]llo` matches `hello` and `hallo`, but not `hillo`

Here is a [Lua script](http://redis.io/commands/eval) that you can use to find all keys that do not contain a colon (`:`):

```
local keys = {}
local cursor = "0"

repeat
  local ret = redis.call("scan", cursor)
  cursor = ret[1]
  for _, key in ipairs(ret[2]) do
    if not string.find(key, ":", 1, true) then
      keys[#keys + 1] = key
    end
  end
until cursor == "0"

return keys
```

Comment: Also, wanted to mention that there's a character omission syntax `[^:]` or character range omission like `[^a-z]`

Comment: Just use grep: `redis-cli -p 6380 keys '*' | grep -v:`